# Multiply with decimal numbers in bash

Tags: bash, dash-shell

When i run

```
p=0.1
k=2
while [ $p \< 1 ]
do
    echo $p
    p=$(echo "scale=2; $p*$k" | bc)
done
```

i have this result

```
0.1
.2
.4
.8
```

What can i do to have 0.1, 0.2, 0.4 and 0.8 ?

Comment: Before the echo check with an if if the 1st char of p is a point and if so add a 0 in front of it?

Comment: this is a pure programming question and probably belongs on stackoverflow instead...

Answer (score 3):

Use `printf` instead of echo to format it:

`printf %0.1f\\n $p`

Output:

```
$ p=0.1; k=2
$ while [ $p \< 1 ]; do     printf %0.1f\\n $p ;     p=$(echo "scale=2; $p*$k" | bc); done
0.1
0.2
0.4
0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do use seq and printf to solve my problem.
check this:

```
for i in $(seq .1 .2 1); do printf "%0.1f\n" "$i"; done
```

Maybe this will help you to continue.